# TYPO3 6.2: Image-Slider with Hyperlink from Page Ressources

Tags: typo3, typoscript, typo3-6.2.x

I did a well working Imageslider from the page ressources. Now I'm trying to hyperlink those Images with a Link also provided in the ressource. This is what I have so far:

TS:

```
lib.headerimage = COA_INT
lib.headerimage {
    1 = COA
    1 {
        stdWrap.required = 1
        stdWrap.outerWrap.cObject = TEXT
        stdWrap.outerWrap.cObject.value = <li><img src=" | " /></li>

        2 = IMG_RESOURCE
        2 {
            file {
                import.data = levelmedia:-1, slide
                import.listNum = 0
                treatIdAsReference = 1
            }
        }   
    }
    2 < .1
    2.2.file.import.listNum = 1
    3 < .1
    3.2.file.import.listNum = 2
}
```

Layout:

```
<div class="headerimage">
    <ul>
        <f:render section="headerimage" />
    </ul>
</div>
```

This Results in the expected HTML Output

```
<ul>
    <li>
        <img />
    </li>
</ul>
```

But I want the following Output

```
<ul>
    <li>
        <a href="link_from_page_ressource">
            <img />
        </a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

How do I get those Links around my Images?

Thanks in advance

UPDATE

Solution:

```
lib.headerimage = COA
lib.headerimage {
    1 = FILES
    1 {
        references {
            data = levelmedia:-1, slide
        }
        renderObj = COA
        renderObj {
            wrap = <li>|</li>

            1 = IMAGE
            1 {
                file.import.data = file:current:publicUrl
                altText.data = file:current:title
                stdWrap.typolink.parameter.data = file:current:link
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: don't use COA_INT, it's not cached and will disable the possibility to statically cache the page with nc_staticfilecache completely. Use COA instead

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You shoul use `FILES` to handle this. Use something like (not tested!)

```
lib.headerimage = COA
lib.headerimage {
    wrap = <ul>|</ul>

    10 = FILES
    10 {
        references {
            data = levelmedia:-1, slide
        }

        renderObj = COA
        renderObj {
            10 = IMAGE
            10 {
                file.import.data = file:current:publicUrl
                altText.data = file:current:title
                stdWrap.typolink.parameter.data = file:current:link
                wrap = <li>|</li>
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This nearely what I want to have.

But...

The generated HTML looks like this:
<ul><a><li></li></a></ul>

And I want to have
<ul><li><a></a></li></ul>

Is there a way to get this HTML?

Comment: OK, got it. My question is updated with my new Code. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

Can you try this?

```
lib.headerimage = COA
lib.headerimage {
   wrap = <ul>|</ul>

        1 = IMAGE
        1 {
            file {
                import.data = levelmedia:-1, slide
                import.listNum = 0
                treatIdAsReference = 1
            }
            stdWrap.typolink.parameter.data = file:current:link
            stdWrap.outerWrap = <ul>|</ul>
        }   

    2 < .1
    2.file.import.listNum = 1
    3 < .1
    3.file.import.listNum = 2
}
```

Comment: Oh, Merec was first! :-) His should be working better, try both

Comment: Thank you, I used the one from Merec and modified it a little bit to fit my expected HTML Output

Answer (score 1):

```
lib.randomImage = COA_INT
lib.randomImage.10 = FILES
lib.randomImage.10.sorting = rand()
lib.randomImage.10 {
  references {
    table = pages
    data = levelmedia:-1, slide
    treatIdAsReference = 1
  }
  maxItems= 1
  renderObj = COA
  renderObj {
    10 = IMAGE
    10 {
      file {
        import {
          data = file:current:publicUrl
        }
      }
    }
  }
  stdWrap {
    wrap = |
  }
}
```

Reference link: http://www.t3hut.com/blog/post/news/detail/News/random-image-from-page-resources-files-in-typo3-62.html

This ts works for me !